# Unicodeerror while getting GCP PubSub topic policy in python

Tags: python-2.7, google-cloud-pubsub, google-cloud-platform

I have a function which gets the policy details of a topic on Google Cloud PubSub. I am getting the policy and adding permissions in it and then updating it. I am using one of the sample code from [python sample docs](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/iot/api-client/manager/manager.py). I am using create_iot_topic function.
My code is as follows:

```
def create_iot_topic(topic_url):
    # eg: topic_url = 'projects/<projectname>/topics/<topicname>'
    topic1 = pubsub_client.topic(topic_url)
    print(topic_url)
    policy = topic1.get_iam_policy()
    publishers = policy.get('roles/pubsub.publisher', [])
    publishers.add(policy.service_account(
            'cloud-iot@system.gserviceaccount.com'))
    policy['roles/pubsub.publisher'] = publishers
    topic1.set_iam_policy(policy)

    return topic1
```

While calling this function, I am getting an error on line number 5 (get_iam_policy() function):

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2019' in position 1438: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I need help resolving this issue. Can someone give me some point me where I am going wrong.

Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code in the given link above was updated recently and now there is no error.